# Union of two circles is star domain with center any of the circles center

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm trying to prove that a power series $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n (z-a)^n$ with a positive finite radius of convergence $r$, then $\exists z_0, |z_0-a|=r$ such that $\nexists \Omega, D(a,r) \subset \Omega, z_0 \in \Omega$ and $\tilde{f} \in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ with $\tilde{f}|_{D(a,r)}=f$.
Any idea of a simple proof of the fact state in the title?

Comment: The "fact stated in the title" seems easy to prove, but how will it help for what you're "trying to prove"?

Comment: The "fact stated in the title" is wrong formulated this way. If two open disks intersect, the union is star shaped, but the center may not be chosen among the centers of the disks. To prove the existence of a singular point on the circle $C(a,r)$, argue by contradiction, and observe that the open sets $\Omega_{z_0}$ associated to the points $z_0$ on $C(a,r)$ would cover the closed disk $\overline{D}(a,r)$. .